Increasing the spacing around all tikzpictures
I know I can easily increase the space a tikzpicture takes by
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
    y\tikz {\fill circle (2pt); \node[fit=(current bounding box), inner sep=2pt, draw] {};}x
\end{document}

Now I have many tikzpictures, so I tried
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{every picture/.append code={\node[fit=(current bounding box), inner sep=2pt, draw] {};}}
\begin{document}
    y\tikz {\fill circle (2pt);}x
\end{document}

which fails with dimension too large. I guess the code is evaluated multiple times, or what's causing the error?

At the beginning of the picture, the bounding box is zero by zero. I assume something is trying to divide by zero. Also, although you can append code to styles, I'm not sure it works quite like this. Use the backgrounds library with a fully transparent setting instead. (Or just use a \path if that's an option.

Why don't you just say \tikz{\node [fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,outer sep=2pt] {};} or whatever? [But hopefully you're not really using tikz to draw dots.]

@cfr, No, of course the picture is more complicated. Because I have many pictures, I want to globally increase their bonding boxes' size. But backgrounds is a good hint. That worked.

The contents of every picture is executed at the beginning of tikzpicture, when the bounding box is zero by zero. Presumably this leads to a division by zero responsible for the error.
You want the code the be executed not at the start but the end of tikzpicture. The backgrounds library can be used for this by creating a background rectangle which is empty. By default, the border is framed with a draw line, so pass draw=none to render it invisible and use outer frame sep to set the padding.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={show background rectangle,background rectangle/.style={draw=none,outer frame sep=2pt}}}
\begin{document}
  y\tikz {\fill circle (2pt);}x
\end{document}

Imagery is currently suspended due to Okular-on-X bug. Apologies for the disruption to visual services.
